# using replicate() to roll 100 dice 10,000 times; unexpected results

Tags: r

In an EdX R stats class, we are asked to look at the proportion of times a '6' is rolled in a set of 100 die rolls. Then we are asked to roll 100 dice 10,000 times, to see the standard deviation of the difference in means from the 100-die rolls.

The results of the 100-die rolls are as expected; around 0.1703 or so (1/6 = 0.1666667)

But when I load up replicate() to throw sets of 100 dice 10,000 times to see 10,000 means, the results are not what I expect. I don't see any values outside  the range of a z-score = 2:

```
set.seed(1)
# get mean of 100 dice rolls
mean100dice <- function(){
   n=100
   x <- replicate(n, sample(1:6, n, replace=TRUE), simplify='vector')
   mean(x==6)
}
mean100dice() #these come out as expected

means10k <- replicate(10000, mean100dice(),simplify='vector')
p = 1/6
z = (means10k - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)
mean(z > 2)       ## I expect this to be > 0
range(means10k)   ## sanity check

> mean(z > 2)
[1] 0
> range(means10k)
[1] 0.1522 0.1806
```

Comment: Your code does not define `n` outside of the function `mean100dice`  yet you use it in your definition of z.    What value does n have?  Please actually test what value it has.

Comment: I think that did it (the n value). mean(z>2) now 0.0227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, you set `n <- 100` instead of `n <- 10000` when calculating `z`.

It's a good idea to provide explicit variable names, so you don't mixed up. For example, you need to distinguish `n_dice_rolls` and `n_replicates`.

---

Incidentally, your code for calculating the mean of 100 dice rolls is not correct.

`sample(1:6, n, replace=TRUE)` rolls `n` dice; you don't need to call `replicate()` as well. I think you want something like this.

```
roll_nd6 <- function(n_dice) {
  sample(1:6, n_dice, replace = TRUE)
}
get_fraction_of_sixes_from_rolling_nd6 <- function(n_dice) {
  mean(roll_nd6(n_dice) == 6L)
}
monte_carlo_simulate_get_fraction_of_sixes <- function(n_replications, n_dice) {
  replicate(
    n_replications, 
    get_fraction_of_sixes_from_rolling_nd6(n_dice),
    simplify = "vector"
  )
}
calc_z_score <- function(actual_p, expected_p) {
  (actual_p - expected_p) / 
    sqrt(expected_p * (1 - expected_p) / length(actual_p))
}
actual_fraction_of_sixes <- monte_carlo_simulate_get_fraction_of_sixes(10000, 100)
z_scores <- calc_z_score(actual_fraction_of_sixes, 1 / 6)
```

Comment: Thank you for the naming and the clarification on sample(). The results still show 40% of z scores being above 2; range(z_scores) = -31.30495  43.82693; something is not right still

Comment: Thank you all; the issue ultimately was not using absolute value of the z score: mean(_abs_(z_scores) > 2).

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in `mean100dice`: You sample 100 dice, and replicate that 100 times, so it's actually not the average of a 100 dice, but of 100*100 = 10,000 dice. Of course, the mean of that is going to be much closer to p on average.